# How does someone share a drive to be available for my containers?

Tags: docker, windows

I have been trying to setup my ASP.Net Core project with docker support, but it seems like I am failing to share my `C:\` drive?

[image]

Following that link I have encountered [these documentations](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#shared-drives) stating that I should..

> allow connections to 10.0.75.1 on port 445 (the Windows host) from 10.0.75.2 (the virtual machine)

.. which I did, but I nevertheless ended up getting the same error message. So I have tried to follow some further instructions and tried to [reinstall the File and Print sharing service on the Hyper-V virtual network card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42203488/settings-to-windows-firewall-to-allow-docker-for-windows-to-share-drive/43904051#43904051). Wich has lead me to another (Windows related) error;

[image]

*Apparently*, the latest Windows 10 release does not support/allow uninstalling `File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks` but instead throws the `0x80071779 error`.

Thus there does not seem to be any "solution" to now share a drive on docker without any "hacky" solutions, no? Have I maybe missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly I have solved that error by pressing on "Reset credentials" in `Docker -> Settings -> Shared Drives` and typing in the exact same account information I had before (admin account).